# Socket.io and node.js, can't understand memory usage

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, socket.io

I currently use socket.io v1.4.2 and node.js v0.10.29 on my server.
I try to track a memory leak in my app, I'm not sure, but I think socket.io is a part of my problem.

So here a code of the server (demo example):

```
var server = require ('http').createServer ();
var io = require ('socket.io')(server);

io.on ("connection", function (socket) {

    socket.on ('disconnect', function (data) { /* Do nothing */ });
});
```

Step 1 : Memory : 58Mb

Step 2 : I create A LOT of clients (~10000), Memory : 300 Mb

Step 3 : I close all clients and waiting the GC doing his work

Step 4 : I look at my memory : 100 Mb :'(

Step 5 : Same as step 2 and 3

Step 6 : Memory 160Mb...

And so on and the memory keeps growing.

I presume the GC was lazy so I retry with the follow code :

```
setInterval (function () {
    global.gc ();
}, 30000);
```

And I start my app.js with :

```
node --expose-gc app.js
```

But I had the same result.

Finally I try

```
var server = require ('http').createServer ();
var io = require ('socket.io')(server);

clients = {};
io.on ("connection", function (socket) {

    clients[socket.id] = socket;        
    socket.on ('disconnect', function (data) { 
        delete clients[socket.id];
    });

});
```

And I had the same result.
How can I free this memory ?

**EDIT**

I create snapshot directly on my main source.

I install the new module with the follow command :

```
 npm install heapdump
```

I write in my code this :

```
 heapdump = require ('heapdump');
 setInterval (function () { heapdump.writeSnapshot (); }, 30000);
```

It took heapdump of the program every 30 seconds, and save it in the current directory.
I read the heapdump with the module 'profiles' of Chrome.

So, the issue is probably socket.io, cause I found many strings not released, that I emit with socket.
Perhaps I don't write the emit in the right way ?
I do that :

```
     var data1 = [1, 2, 3];
     var data2 = [4, 5, 6];
     var data3 = [7, 8, 9];
     socket.emit ('b', data1, data2, data3);
     data1 = [];
     data2 = [];
     data3 = [];
```

And in my snapshot say that the program keeps the following string: "b [1, 2, 3] [4, 5, 6] [7, 8, 9]" in my memory, millions of time
What I'm suppose to do ?

I also make an another (perhaps stupid ?) test :

```
    var t1 = new Date ();

    ...

    var t2 = new Date ();
    var data1 = [1, 2, 3];
    var data2 = [4, 5, 6];
    var data3 = [7, 8, 9];
    socket.emit ('b', data1, data2, data3);
    data1 = [];
    data2 = [];
    data3 = [];

    console.log ("LAG: " + t2 - t1);
    t1 = new Date ();
```

I had this result :

```
    LAG: 1
    LAG: 1
    ...
    LAG: 13
    LAG: 2
    LAG: 26
    LAG: 3
    ...
    LAG: 100
    LAG: 10
    LAG: 1
    LAG: 1
    LAG: 120
    ...
    keeps growing
```

**EDIT 2 :**

This is my entire test code :

```
/* Make snapshot every 30s in current directory */
heapdump = require ('heapdump');
setInterval (function () { heapdump.writeSnapshot (); }, 30000);

/* Create server */
var server = require ('http').createServer ();
var io = require ('socket.io')(server);
var t1 = new Date ();

clients = {};
io.on ("connection", function (socket) {

    clients[socket.id] = socket;        
    socket.on ('disconnect', function (data) { 
        delete clients[socket.id];
    });
});

setInterval (function () { 

    var t2 = new Date ();
    for (c in clients) {
        var data1 = [1, 2, 3];
        var data2 = [4, 5, 6];
        var data3 = [7, 8, 9];
        clients[c].emit ('b', data1, data2, data3);
        data1 = [];
        data2 = [];
        data3 = [];
    }
    console.log ("LAG: " + t2 - t1);
    t1 = new Date (); 
}, 100);
```

I don't give the code of client. Because I assume that: if the problem is in the client, so it's a security issue. In fact, it will be an easy way to saturate the RAM of the server. So it's a kind of better DDOS, I juste hope the problem is not in the client.

Comment: We probably need to see more of your actual code used in the test on both client and server.   Do you know for a fact that all your clients disconnect and the server knows they are all disconnected and has removed all their socket objects from the index you create?  Did all the data you sent from the server get delivered to the client successfully?  Are you using `console.log()` statements anywhere that could be accumulating?

Comment: Ok i just edit my post

Comment: For starters on your server, `c.emit ('b', data1, data2, data3);` should be `clients[c].emit('b', data1, data2, data3);` `c.emit()` was probably throwing an exception because `c` is the `socket.id` string and strings don't have a `.emit()` method.

Comment: My bad, it was a typo when I recopy my code

Comment: I asked you several other questions you did not answer.

Comment: Hey, yes you right. So after a while, server disconnect all clients. For the second question, idk how to know that, but the server don't seem to send another packet (I say that because I cannot see any variation in CPU/RAM usage and no packet sending). For the rest, this is my all code, so no, I only use console.log at the end of my code.

Comment: I see the LAG  `console.log()` in your `setInterval()`.  That is firing every 100ms.  You can check `Object.keys(clients).length` on the server to see how many connected clients your server still thinks it has.  socket.io will buffer outgoing messages if they are being sent when the socket is not connected or otherwise ready to have data sent.  That's why I asked because your heap snapshot makes it looks like you have lots of outgoing messages in the heap so that would be one suspect.

Comment: You should examine the heap snapshot more to see if you have zillions of socket objects in the heap to determine if they are not being cleaned up or to see what kinds of objects you have in the heap.  The info is all there in the heap for exactly what data structures are not being freed.  You have to learn more about what's there.

Comment: Sorry, but I just want to know how to create a simple server without memory leak. I mean where is my error in the code ?? I'm not supposed to reverse socket.io or all my heap.
Seriously, I just want to use a very simple library to create a very simple server. And.. I got memory leak, how to fix it ? Which part in my code is wrong ?

I make effort to give a very simple proof example who give me memory leaks. IN ORDER TO not have to examine all my dump.

Where is my error ?

If I didn't make mistake that simply mean I just found a crazy hack for all server that uses socket.io.

Comment: And for informations : Object.keys(clients).length give me the right number of connected clients.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit based on the server code you included**

On your server:

```
c.emit ('b', data1, data2, data3);`
```

should be changed to:

```
clients[c].emit('b', data1, data2, data3);
```

`c.emit()` was probably throwing an exception because `c` is the `socket.id` string and strings don't have a `.emit()` method.

**Original answer**

What you need to determine is whether the growth in memory is actually memory that is allocated within the node.js heap or if it's free memory that has just not been returned to the operating system and is available for future reuse within node.js?  Measuring the memory used by the node.js process is useful to see what it has taken from the system and that should not continually go up forever over time, but it doesn't tell you what is really going on inside.

FYI, as long as your node.js app has a few free cycles, you shouldn't ever have to manually call the GC.  It will do that itself.

The usual way to measure what is being used within the node.js heap is to take a heap snapshot, run your Steps 1-4, take a heap snapshot, run those steps again, take another heap snapshot, diff the snapshots and see what memory in the node.js heap is actually different between the two states.

That will show you what is actually in use within node.js that has changed.

Here's an article on taking heap snapshots and reading them in the debugger: https://strongloop.com/strongblog/how-to-heap-snapshots/

Comment: Ok I did it, I create snapshot directly on my main source. So, the issue is probably socket.io, cause I found many strings not released, that I emit with socket.
Perhaps I don't write the emit in the right way ?
I do that :
         
         data1 = [1, 2, 3];
         data2 = [4, 5, 6];
         data3 = [7, 8, 9];
         socket.emit ('b', data1, data2, data3);
         data1 = [];
         data2 = [];
         data3 = [];
And in my snapshot say that the program keeps the following string: "[1, 2, 3] [4, 5, 6] [7, 8, 9]" in my memory, millions of time
What I'm suppose to do ?.

Comment: Yeah, it was a typo, but what about my main problem of memory leak ^^ ?